# ASP.NET MVC 5 doesn't update table rows and send details(with datatables)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I want to update my datatable rows and send submit. But dont update, because my row data send null.How to send I select row and update row and submit.

```
 @model List<ASTek.Models.CustomersModel>
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customers";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
     @using (Html.BeginForm("TopluSms", "Mobil", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive" id="tblCustomer" style="font-size:11px; position:center">
        <thead>
            <tr style="background-color:#8c7fcf">
                <th>Müşteri</th>
                <th>Telefon</th>
                <th>Bakiye</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirmaName)</td>                  
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.TLF)</td>
                    <td> @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Bakiye)</td>
                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LOGICALREF)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IHTAR, new { style = "width:18px;height:18px;" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="@item.LOGICALREF" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-info" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        <tbody>
    </table>
}
```

this view page and my controller. My database variable table name and I have to use it like that SQL,

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TopluSms(CustomersModel model)
    {
        string LOGICALREF = model.LOGICALREF;
        string TLF = model.TLF;
        string active = "0";
        CustomersModel items = new CustomersModel();
        string a = User.Identity.Name;
        HomeController.sqlconnection con = new HomeController.sqlconnection();
        string firmsec = "UPDATE dbo.LG_005_CLCARD  SET TELNRS1='" + TLF + "',WARNFAXNR='" + active + "' where LOGICALREF=" + LOGICALREF + "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(firmsec, con.connect());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.connect().Close();
        return RedirectToAction("TopluSms");

    }
```

My controller select list and send datatable.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TopluSms()
    {
        string aa = User.Identity.Name;
        HomeController.sqlconnection con = new HomeController.sqlconnection();
        string FIRMA = "select t.FIRMA,t.donem FROM dbo.TBLFRM as t where T.USERNAME='" + aa + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(FIRMA, con.connect());
        SqlDataReader rdrr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        rdrr.Read();
        string firma = rdrr["FIRMA"].ToString();
        string donem = rdrr["DONEM"].ToString();
        string Musteriler = "SELECT CLCARD.LOGICALREF, CLCARD.DEFINITION_ AS  UNVANI,CLCARD.TELNRS1, CAST((SUM((1 - CLFLINE.SIGN) * CLFLINE.AMOUNT) - SUM(CLFLINE.SIGN * CLFLINE.AMOUNT)) as DECIMAL(15, 2)) AS[BAKIYE],CLCARD.WARNFAXNR AS IHTAR " +
            "FROM dbo.LG_" + firma + "_" + donem + "_CLFLINE as CLFLINE INNER JOIN dbo.LG_" + firma + "_CLCARD as CLCARD ON CLFLINE.CLIENTREF = CLCARD.LOGICALREF AND CLFLINE.CANCELLED = 0 " +
            "GROUP BY CLCARD.LOGICALREF, CLCARD.CODE, CLCARD.DEFINITION_, CLCARD.ACTIVE, CLCARD.CITY, CLCARD.CAPIBLOCK_CREADEDDATE ,CLCARD.TELNRS1,CLCARD.WARNFAXNR " +
            "HAVING(CLCARD.CODE LIKE '%') and(CLCARD.DEFINITION_ LIKE '%') AND(CLCARD.ACTIVE = 0) " +
            "ORDER BY CLCARD.DEFINITION_ DESC ";
        // var model = new List<CustomersModel>();
        List<CustomersModel> items = new List<CustomersModel>();
        using (SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(Musteriler, con.connect()))
        {
            //con.connect().Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {

                var musteri = new CustomersModel();
                musteri.LOGICALREF = rdr[0].ToString();
                musteri.FirmaName = rdr[1].ToString();
                ViewBag.bakiye = rdr[3].ToString();
                musteri.TLF = rdr[2].ToString();
                musteri.Bakiye = rdr[3].ToString();
                if (rdr[4].ToString() == "1") { musteri.IHTAR = true; }
                else { musteri.IHTAR = false; }
                if (Convert.ToDouble(musteri.Bakiye) > 0)
                {
                    musteri.SIGN = "0";
                }
                else
                {
                    musteri.SIGN = "1";
                }
                items.Add(musteri);

            }
            con.connect().Close();
            return View(items);
        }
    }
```

[I want to update datatable row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZcPf.png)

Comment: Are you checking with fiddler or network inspection of the browser that is sending the form to the controller?

Comment: with your loop a lot of input with same name

Comment: I want to update datatable row

Comment: In the form you have multiple `CustomersModel` objects. I suggest you to remove form and use ajax there. When you click button just get the related data and send it to your action.

Comment: I do not know how to do it. I've never used ajax

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a `List` of models there but your `Action TopluSms` is for a single model.
However, If you change the `parameter` of your function to `List<CustomersModel> models`, that may work but its not the proper way to do this kind of stuff.

Try to use any frontend grid management framework like [KendoUI](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index), [JQGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/free-jqgrid.github.io) etc.

Read there documentation and implement. They use `ajax` for `CRUD`.

And try to follow any `Design Pattern` for your backend code.